# Security and Webflow in Spring 3.1 MVC web application configuration example?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I am trying to add webflow and security configuration to an operational Spring 3.1 MVC web application.

I got rid of the `application-context.xml` file and `ContextLoaderListener`, and use `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` with an `@EnableWebMvc` `@Configuration` annotated class.

Yet, when I follow the webflow and security documentation, it seems like an `application-context.xml` file and `ContextLoaderListener` are necessary. The later seems to create a conflict with `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`.

Can anyone provide a simple but complete Spring 3.1 MVC Web Application configuration with webflow and security enabled example? I am looking for a `web.xml` example file, plus any other required files.

If someone has a complete sample application downloadable online, it is even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works when deploying to Tomcat 7:

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false">

    <!-- Context Params -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mypackage.web.WebConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Filters --> 
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Declaring and configuring the default Spring Servlet -->
    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>springExample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <!-- Enabling annotation configuration for web app -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>

        <!-- Loading order -->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springExample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    

</web-app>
```

### WebConfig

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource({ "/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml", "/WEB-INF/spring-webflow.xml"})
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...

}
```

*Caveat:* using `@Import(SomeConfig.class)` does not work anymore. It causes initialization issues. The workaround is to move the content of `SomeConfig.class` to `WebConfig.class` itself.

It is important to add proper maven dependencies, otherwise, Tomcat results in 404 Resource not found error messages:

### pom.xml

```
<properties>
    ...
    <spring.framework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.webflow.version>2.3.1.RELEASE</spring.webflow.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```